# Number of ways to obtainin two pair in poker set up question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The book I'm reading is telling me that the number of ways to select two pairs is $(_{13}C_2)(_4C_{2})(_4C_2) * 44$ which is $($ways to select two ranks$)$$\times$$($ways to select two suits for first pair$)\times($ways to select suits for second pair$)\times($remaining cards$)$.

What I don't understand is why are each of these being multiplied together to calculate this?  I also don't understand how $44$ is the cards remaining when $52-4$ cards should be $48$ cards.  I have a feeling I'm not understanding a basic statistical general rule.

Comment: Haven't you learned the multiplication principle ?

Comment: I suspect that the book is enumerating the number of ways to get two pairs and no full house. This is why the remaining cards are 44 because you can't select a card with there same rank as one in the pair $(52 -8 = 44)$.

Comment: I understand the multiplication principle but I don't see how it applies to this problem.  If $A_1, A_2, ..., A_k$ sets have $n_1, n_2, ..., n_k$ elements respectively, then there are $\prod_i n_i$ ways to pick an element from each set.  I don't see how I can break this problem into sets.

Answer (score 1):

- Re why multiply, you better go through an elementary presentation on [probability rules.](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m170/ch05-rul.html)
- Regarding $44$, do you understand if it is written as $\binom{11}1\binom41$ ?

---

*Added explanation*

For why multiply, you could look at the $13$ ranks (ace through K) as types of bread (say) and the $4$ suits as the spread (butter, cheese, etc) on them !

The two pairs can have any two from the $13$ ranks: $\binom{13}2$

*Each* of the two chosen ranks can be associated with any of the $4$ suits: $\binom42\binom42$

The fifth card can be from any of the remaining $11$ ranks, and any of the $4$ suits: $\binom{11}1\binom41$

It would help you if you studied computations of other types of [poker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability) hands to get a hang of it.

---

*Why do we multiply ?*

Say you want to know the number of ways **one** pair can be obtained. There are $13$ ranks, (A through K), so obviously we could choose any one rank from $13\;i.e.\;\binom{13}1$ ways. Suppose we choose K. We are not done yet. We also need to specify which two of the four suits they belong to, which is $\binom42 = 6$ ways, viz$\;$ KS-KH, $\;$ KS-KD, $\;$ KS-KC, $\;$ KH-KD, $\;$ KH-KC $\;$ and$\;$ KD-KC.

So the # of ways of forming a pair from **any** rank is $\binom{13}1\times\binom42$

You should be able to build on this, just remember that once you have chosen two pairs, only $11$ ranks are available from which the *single* can be chosen.

Comment: I can't see how these probability rules relate to the combinatorial nature of this problem.

Comment: I have added some more explanation.

Comment: Could you explain why these are being multiplied together?  I don't understand how I would break this problem into a general model.

Comment: Added "Why do we multiply" ? You make a first set of choices, and if further choices are needed, you make them from the reduced sample space available at any stage.

Comment: I still don't understand why you're multiplying $_{13}C_1 \times _4C_2$.  I understand that the number of ways to choose $1$ from $13$ is $_{13}C_1$ because I can choose any of the $13$.  I understand that the number of ways you can choose $2$ cards from $4$ is $_4C_2$.  But why does multiplying them together give me the number of ways of forming a pair?  If I'm trying to put two cards into a $2$-tuple, why wouldn't it be something along the lines of $(52, X)$?  Where $52$ is the number of cards in spot $1$ and $X$ is the number of cards available to choose to make a pair?

Comment: Well, in your method, the number will be $(52\cdot3)/ 2 = 78 = \binom{13}1\binom42$ The division by $2$ in the former method is needed because you will be double counting, say $KS-KH$ and $KH-KS$. It is best to treat the rank and suit as independent attributes to keep things simple. That is why though the last multiplier $44$ in the book formulation is correct, I prefer $\binom{11}1\binom41$ for greater clarity. Remember, you were asking why not $48$.

Answer (score 0):

Broadly speaking the reason we are multiplying is that each of those choices is in some respect independent. Since our choice of ranks doesn't affect the number of cards they are independent.

As to the 44 issue I think others have covered that neatly, since we only want two pair and not a full house we can't pick either of the leftover cards from the 4 choose 2.

If you want a better challenge you might think of a worn out deck where there are only 2 twos. or 3 threes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer you are looking for lies in the rule for calculating the number of posibilites of two disjoint sets A and B being N(A, B) = N(A) * N(B) where N(A) is the number of possibilities in set A. In this case there are two independent attributes: suit and rank. This means once you calculate the number of ways to pull two ranks from thirteen possible, you still have to deal with the independent event of choosing the suit of those two ranks. Then, for the fifth card, you know that you cannot choose either rank you currently have (making the hand a full-house), nor can you choose a card you already have (unless you are cheating), which means there are 8 cards you cannot choose to be the last card. This leaves 44 cards to choose from.

See
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180217175037/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/56158.html)